# React Native + Flux, unresponsive dispatcher

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm building my first react-native application. I'm used to building React applications and do so using the Flux MVC pattern. I have (correctly) integrated Flux into my React Native project but the `register` function on the dispatcher seems to be completely unresponsive.

**Actions.js**

```
import AppConstants from '../constants';
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher';

export default {
    setUser (user) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: AppConstants.SET_USER,
            user: user
        })
    }
}
```

**Store.js**

```
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher';
import AppConstants from '../constants';
import assign from 'object-assign';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

const CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

const AppStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {

    emitChange () {
        this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
    },

    addChangeListener (callback) {
        this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    removeChangeListener (callback) {
        this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
    },

    dispatcherIndex: register(function (action) {
        console.log(action); // <-- No response
    })

});

export default AppStore;
```

**Dispatcher.js**

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';
module.exports = new Dispatcher();
```

---

I have even tried rewriting the Dispatcher.js file so that the `dispatch` and `register` functions are hard-coded. I get a response from `dispatch()` but never from `register()`.

**Dispatcher2.js**

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';

const flux = new Dispatcher();

export function register (callback) {
    console.log('event!');
    return flux.register(callback);
}

export function dispatch (action) {
    console.log(action);
    flux.dispatch(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this documentation. I don't know about your code but in this way also we can use flux. http://fluxxor.com/ . This is very simple and easy to use. If this is helpful to your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the code for the store? Regardless, is there a reason that the dispatchIndex is being called as a method when the rest of your attributes are pure functions?

At the risk of giving you code that doesn't help, here's how I learned to utilize stores per the react flux documentation for vanilla flux:

```
import Immutable from 'immutable'
import {ReduceStore} from 'flux/utils'
import myActionTypes from './../data/myThing/myActionTypes'
import dispatcher from '../data/dispatcher'
import AppConstant from '../data/myThing/AppConstant'

class myStore extends ReduceStore{
    constructor(){
        super(dispatcher);
    }
getInitialState(){
return Immutable.OrderedMap({});
}
reduce(state,action){
    switch(action.actionType){
        case AppConstant.SET_USER:
            return state.set({//data you want to set})
        case AppConstant.OTHER_THING:
            //additional logic
```

Hopefully this is useful, and not just me telling you to abandon your code for something unrelated.